# aura if comparing iteration variable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, aura-if

I would like to know if it is possible to evaluate the expresion not comparing to a constant but instead to another variable, like the iteration variable from aura:iteration.

I want to evaluate the expression for every iteration. This is my code

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.tiles}" var="tile" end="7">
   <aura:if isTrue="{!v.tileName == tile}">

       <!-- content renders if true --> 

   <aura:set attribute="else">

       <!-- content renders if false -->
   </aura:set>
</aura:if></aura:iteration>
```

I dont know if it is unsupported or if I am making a syntax error but it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do, like compare !tile.name == tile.someOtherName ?

Comment: you probably want to check [Expression Functions Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm)

Comment: Share the type of tiles, tileName attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere in code you've omitted. Here's a self-contained example of comparing the current iterator to a specified value:

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="List" default="[1,2,3]" />
    <aura:attribute name="current" type="Integer" default="2" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.current == item}">
            <div>Current: {!item}</div>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div>Not Current: {!item}</div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

---

Output:

```
Not Current: 1
Current: 2
Not Current: 3
```

Comment: You understood my point and your example has showed me that compring can be possible. I have problem with my v.current variable. It is calculated in the js controller and I can debug it but I dont know how to debug it in the component. I will try lightning inspector and use eq instead of == for comparing.

Comment: @ElkCor I suspect maybe you didn't store the value back into the data set? You can't use an evaluated value without storing it back in to the data.